# Show a floating always-on-top image of dvorak keyboard on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm on the latest Ubuntu. I want to try out dvorak keyboard layout. To do so, I thought it would help to have an image of that keyboard floating on top of all the other windows (but able to drag it around). Is there some way to do something like this easily?

I could just grab an image somewhere of it, but how to make it visible always on top and movable?

Update: I discovered that you can do this from the keyboard layout control but it's huge and I can't figure out a way to make it smaller. And all the extra characters (4 on each key) is distracting. So... I'm still looking for a solution with the added criteria that it doesn't take up half the screen and either I can use an image of my choice, or it has fewer characters marked on each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos on switching to Dvorak!  Once you get used to it, you'll never want to go back...

Previously in Ubuntu, you could right click on the title bar of an application and the menu would include "always on top" which would keep that app above all other windows.  I can't say if this is in the most recent Ubuntu releases, as I haven't played with it in several months.  Assuming this option still exists, you can open the Dvorak image of your choice in the viewer of your choice, then set it to "always on top" and voila, you're all set!